# How to navigate Neo4j with Neo4j.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I'm using Neo4j 2.0.1 and Neo4j.rb 3.0

I've the following query:

```
<%  xxx = Neo4j::Session.query('match (q:Complex_Type)<-[:_IS_A]-(m) return m;') %>
```

with the following partial results:

```
outgoing_relationships: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/25/relationships/out
labels: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/25/labels
```

Now, going ahead, which is the correct way to obtain labels (without using get & post)?

TIA

Paolo

Answer (score 1):

Assuming at least Neo4j.rb 3.0 RC2 or higher:

You can modify your query to look like this:

```
result = Neo4j::Session.query('match (q:Complex_Type)<-[:_IS_A]-(m) return m, LABELS(m) as labels;')
result.each do |response|
  response.m
  # => the node
  response.labels
  # => an array containing strings of the node's labels
end
```

Be aware that if you omit the `as labels` part of your return statement, the method will actually be `LABELS(m)` and you'll only be able to get to it using `send`.

```
result.send("LABELS(m)")
```

...and that's kind of goofy.

If you want to rewrite it to be a bit friendlier, you could also do this:

```
result = Neo4j::Session.query.match('(q:Complex_Type)<-[:_IS_A]-(m)').return('m, LABELS(m) as labels')
```

You mention Neo4j.rb but these examples all use the neo4j-core gem's Query class. If you happen to be using models with ActiveNode in Neo4j.rb 3.0, the best way to do this is with the `labels` method on the node, it will give you an array of the labels.

In case you don't have a model setup, that would be as simple as:

```
class ComplexType
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  has_many :in, :other_things, model_class: false, type: '_IS_A'
end
```

From there, it's as easy as:

```
a_complex_type.other_things.each { |m| m.labels }
```

I think the downside to this is that it might perform an additional cypher query when you call `labels`, so if that concerns you, you could do this:

```
# to return structs that respond to 'm' or 'labels':
a_complex_type.other_things.query_as(:m).return(:m, 'labels(m) as labels')
# for an array where element 0 is the returned 'm' node, element 1 is an array of labels:
a_complex_type.other_things.query_as(:m).pluck(:m, 'labels(m)')
# note that you can omit 'as labels' here since you aren't dealing with a struct
```